# Configurations for connecting multiple sensors to same power source over a distance

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, circuit-design, sensor

I am building a solution that will contain 32 individual identical sensors over the span of 4 feet. I am trying to figure out the best way to provide power to all of them. For testing purposes (visual representation below), I am just using a 3-pin screw terminal (orange block) where I daisy chain ground pins together and then daisy chain the voltage pins. The green wire represents the signal wire, which is not are shared between sensors.

[image: visual representation of circuit connection]

This works fine for testing purposes but it not practical by any means. What are ways that something like this is typical done? A few ideas that I have are as follows I am just not sure the legitimacy of them.

1. Make a 4ft long rigid PCB (seems very expensive) I will add that the width of the board could be very small probably less than half an inch
2. Make smaller rigid PCB boards that snap together
3. Have ground and voltage pads on bottom of PCB that could lay on thin strips of copper to provide voltage to each board. Would need to be a completely custom solution

I am curious if anyone knows other existing solutions that would work for a configuration like the one described above. Or of the solutions that I described which is the most practical.

Comment: What kind of connection do the sensors have?  1/4" quick connect?  PC pin?  Solder lug?

Comment: The sensors can have whatever I want. I am designing them. I am just trying to figure out what is the best way to connect them all together. Right now I just a bunch of little PCBs that I connect together manually with wires using the a screw terminal.

Comment: Are you just trying to power the sensors, or do you care about delivering any signal from them?

Comment: I am just trying to power them, but I will also be delivering a signal from them. However, since each sensor requires its own signal wire I don't think there is away around a custom cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sensors are low current/low voltage, you could make a PC board for each one (are these board-mount sensors?) and then put in a pair of cheap 2-pin headers with readily available premade jumpers like [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/A02KR02KR26E51B/6194801).  This saves you from having to buy a crimper and make 126 terminations per system.

If the sensors are rigidly mounted, a board-to-board connection might make sense, since there will likely be less than an inch between adjacent boards.

Comment: The sensors are board-mounted and I think what you described is the only way that makes sense. I thought of what you said as well, but just wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas I was missing